# Downloading custom dataset for googles custom model maker - TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection

I am following a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-ZyFYniGUsw&t=342s) on training your own custom dataset and I am using this [Collab tutorial](https://colab.research.google.com/github/khanhlvg/tflite_raspberry_pi/blob/main/object_detection/Train_custom_model_tutorial.ipynb#scrollTo=UNRhB8N7GHXj) to do so.

Things go smoothly until I get to step 3 of 'Train the object Detection model'. I get this error

```
ValueError: The size of the train_data (0) couldn't be smaller than batch_size (2). To solve this problem, set the batch_size smaller or increase the size of the train_data.
```

This leads me to believe my train_data is empty which I am confused about. **Am I downloading and loading the dataset correctly?**

This is how I download the dataset

```
!git clone https://github.com/priedejm/shirts.git
!unzip -q shirts/shirts.zip
```

This is how I load the dataset - I am not sure why shirts/train is there twice but thats how the original does it

```
train_data = object_detector.DataLoader.from_pascal_voc(
    'shirts/train',
    'shirts/train',
    ['shirt', 'pants']
)

val_data = object_detector.DataLoader.from_pascal_voc(
    'shirts/validate',
    'shirts/validate',
    ['shirt', 'pants']
)
```

And this is how the tutorial does it

```
!wget https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/data/android_figurine.zip
!unzip -q android_figurine.zip

train_data = object_detector.DataLoader.from_pascal_voc(
    'android_figurine/train',
    'android_figurine/train',
    ['android', 'pig_android']
)

val_data = object_detector.DataLoader.from_pascal_voc(
    'android_figurine/validate',
    'android_figurine/validate',
    ['android', 'pig_android']
)
```

Comment: I don't see that problem. You can check your folders in Collab on the left side to see the directory view. But I see another problem. Your new dataset doesn't have a `.xml` file for every image file. Are you expecting that ? If so you need to clean up.